# using iptables on non rooted android device using system signed app

Tags: android, firewall, iptables

Is there a way to do system wide network filtering on a non rooted android device using a system signed app ?

Similar to apps that are using iptables binary in rooted devices.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible to do that on a non rooted device because iptables requires root permission.

In rooted devices, you should use some apps like SuperUser to grant root permission if an app wants to run iptables.